# Excel VBA Address comparing output non matching addresses

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a workbook that has three tabs. My Customer list Addresses, Outsource customer listing addresses: and Output No Match:.  I am looking to run my list agents an outsource list and if my address list does not match any addresses on the out source list.  It outputs on the No match tab.

I have built a working document but it is so slow and feel someone here could really help point me in the right direction.

All three sheets column headers ("Customer Name","Address 1","Address 2","City","State","Zip Code")

I am using a code similar to the one below to find none matches on all the columns. It only looks at the first few characters in hope to speed things up but i am getting no where fast.

I am running it on a loop somewhat like this which seems to be very incessant and slow when comparing addresses agent 200,000 records.

```
For I = 2 To LastRow

If Left(UCase(Trim(wsAddressS_1.Cells(1 + I, 6).Value)), 5) = 
Left(UCase(VLookLike(wsAddressS_1.Cells(1 + I, 6).Value, wsAddressS_2.Range("F1:F" & LastRow2 + 10))), 5) Then
    Match_Zip = "Match"
Else
    Match_Zip = "No Match"
End If

If strMatchZip <> "Match" Then

            LastRow1 = wsAddressS_4.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wsAddressS_4.Cells(LastRow4 + 1, 1).Value = wsAddressS_1.Cells(1 + I, 1).Value
            wsAddressS_4.Cells(LastRow4 + 1, 2).Value = wsAddressS_1.Cells(1 + I, 2).Value
            wsAddressS_4.Cells(LastRow4 + 1, 3).Value = wsAddressS_1.Cells(1 + I, 3).Value
            wsAddressS_4.Cells(LastRow4 + 1, 4).Value = wsAddressS_1.Cells(1 + I, 4).Value
            wsAddressS_4.Cells(LastRow4 + 1, 5).Value = wsAddressS_1.Cells(1 + I, 5).Value
            wsAddressS_4.Cells(LastRow4 + 1, 6).Value = wsAddressS_1.Cells(1 + I, 6).Value

End If

    Sleep 10
    DoEvents
Next I
```

e.g VLookLike

```
Private Function VLookLike(txt As String, rng As Range) As String
Dim temp As String, e, n As Long, a()
Static RegX As Object
If RegX Is Nothing Then
    Set RegX = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegX
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(\S+).*" & Chr(2) & ".*\1"
    End With
End If
With RegX
    For Each e In rng.Value
        If UCase$(e) = UCase(txt) Then
            VLookLike = e
            Exit For
        End If
        temp = Join$(Array(e, txt), Chr(2))
        If .test(temp) Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve a(1 To 2, 1 To n)
            a(2, n) = e
            Do While .test(temp)
                a(1, n) = a(1, n) + Len(.Execute(temp)(0).submatches(0))
                temp = Replace(temp, .Execute(temp)(0).submatches(0), "")
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End With
If (VLookLike = "") * (n > 0) Then
    With Application
        VLookLike = .HLookup(.Max(.Index(a, 1, 0)), a, 2, False)
    End With
End If
End Function
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would not look at the first few characters. Just see if the strings match. Comparing a shorter strings involves the extra work of splitting the string. If your code is slow, the problem is elsewhere

Comment: I can but the code itself all together works.  It just may take 3 hours to run if it does not crash your excel and or run out of memory.  I really am looking for someone the is good at arrays that could speed up the process. I will shorten the code real fast.

Comment: O gosh there are no vlookups in this file. That would be a nighmare for error catching. "VLookLike" us a custom UDF that finds closest match.

Comment: It may be possible to work with arrays. If so, use those rather than looping worksheets. It will be much faster. If you can do away with regex that would help but not sure if you can.

Comment: Treating the address as 5 different fields is madness. Add a "Full Address" column that concatenates them together, then just do normal vlookups.

Comment: This issue with Full Address is how dirty the data is i am comparing.  In a perfect world scenario you hit the money. Something as simple as a "N" on my address and "North" on the Outsource list could cost millions of lost dollars because i just gave a customer that does not deserve a special pricing promo or vis versa. This is a bandaid file for a program i am writing. My CCO and SVP of marketing wants something for the interim. How would you suggest i handle these scenarios. Street addresses i have found to be much harder to deal with then expected.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read all the code, sorry, but I have had problems on comparing strings. Perhaps it would work if you tell vba that you are gonna compare 2 strings. You could use the function Cstr() for example

```
CStr(Left(UCase(StrAddress), 3)) = CStr(Left(UCase(VLookLike(StrAddress, rng2)), 3))
```

Comment: would you suggest i remove the functions and build this right into the loop itself?

Comment: It would work, as I see, the problem you are having is on comparing strings. Am I right?

Comment: View the file in the link above and you will get an idea.  It is not so much comparing strings but then again it is.  my file runs fine until you start comparing 100 to 200 thousand addresses